# How to split a DOT file with multiple graphs into multiple DOT files using GVPR?

Tags: graph, graphviz

How do you split a file with multiple graphs in the DOT language into multiple DOT files using `gvpr`?

Input (1 file):

```
# single.dot
digraph one {
  a -> b;
}
digraph two {
  c -> d;
}
```

Output (1 graph per file):

```
# one.dot
digraph one {
  a -> b;
}

# two.dot
digraph two {
  c -> d;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
BEG_G {
  fname = sprintf("%s.dot",$G.name);
  writeG($G, fname);
}
```

Comment: This works for me. I would add that in case it is not obvious, the OPP should save this in a file e.g. a file called `split` , and the run `$ gvpr -f split infile.dot`